# Mysql query list results matching each date

Tags: mysql

Not sure how this would work.  I have a between query, but how would I run a query to list results that match each and every day.  Example, enterys that exists on 2011-06-17, 2011-06-18, 2011-06-19 and 2011-06-20

```
SELECT lookup, `loc`, `octect1` ,`octect2` ,`octect3` ,`octect4`, date, time, count(`lookup`) as count FROM index 
WHERE date between '2011-06-17' AND '2011-06-20'
GROUP BY lookup
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on *each and everyday*. IMO, the query you have matches your example.

Comment: I don't want results that match 2011-06-17 and 2011-06-19, just all 4 days.

Comment: Still confused. If you don't want those dates, then you would only match *2 days*, i.e. 2011-06-18 and 2011-06-20. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `BETWEEN`, use comparison operators:

```
SELECT lookup, `loc`, `octect1` ,`octect2` ,`octect3` ,`octect4`, 
       date, time, count(`lookup`) as count 
FROM index  
WHERE date > '2011-06-17' AND date < '2011-06-20' 
GROUP BY lookup 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a difference between BETWEEN and the comparison operators. What is it, exactly?

Comment: I believe BETWEEN is inclusive of start/end dates, equivalent to `date >= $a AND date <= $b`.  See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between